Registry Export result in error writing the file
I get error message when exporting the entire registry, and after some debugging, I found the issue is from the below 2 folders.
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control
The error message that I've been getting is:
"Cannot export C:\Users\Cody\Desktop\1.reg: Error writing the file. There may be a disk or file system error."
I've tried exporting to a new drive, and import someone else's working registry (it failed to import some values), none of which solved the problem.
When I click on the folder Control folder from either registry path, I get error "Cannot display: Error reading the value's contents." Refer to  image below:
https://i.imgur.com/7223Iwi.png
When I try to export either control folder, I get this error "Cannot export C:\Users\Cody\Desktop\1.reg: Error writing the file. There may be a disk or file system error." Refer to image below:
https://i.imgur.com/kJOtYTL.png
I do not want to reinstall windows, or lose my current windows settings, is there a way to resolve this? Thanks!

Some registry keys are restricted and cannot be opened, viewed or exported.
I also tried to export the key CurrentControlSet\Control and got very
fast the error message of
Error Opening Key
An error is preventing this key from being opened.
Details: Access is denied.

You just cannot export the entire registry, since some parts of it
are only for internal usage of Windows itself and are protected
against user access.
I have the feeling that you're trying to solve another problem
with this solution that can't work. It would perhaps be better
to ask about your real problem (in a separate post).

I wasnt able to import the regedit subkey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows NT > CurrentVersion > Schedule > TaskCache > Tree , it kept saying error, after exporting it to the desktop. I think it's okay, because now the Schedule Task seems to work (before it wasn't working). Maybe there is an error in the file somewhere.

I recently explored rates for translation, revision, and proofreading services, and I must say, it's impressive how competitive and reasonable they can be.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
